# Rendering Handlebars templates for the first time but also keeping them around for subsequent renderings?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, handlebars.js

I used Handlebars for quite some time and my approach is to put the template where it's supposed to render in HTML file. For example.

```
<div id="template-parent">
  <script type="text/template" id="template">
    <!-- The template goes here -->
  </script>
</div>
```

The `#template` is suppose to render inside `#template-parent`.

What I can do now is call the template using JavaScript and render it in the proper place with the proper data whenever I want. But what I want is to be able to render it the first time the page loads, with Ruby. But after rendering, I still want to keep the template intact for subsequent renderings. Any ideas how I might be able to achieve it?

Comment: How is your template rendered the first time (without javascript) ? Second question, if you included your template in the page and want it to render it multiple time just why not retrieving the content from the id #template and the render it again (but avoid putting the the template in the object that you want to render otherwise the content will be lost).

Comment: I want my template to render the first time but without JavaScript. Presumably with Server Side language. But even after that I need the template to stay intact so that I can access it in my JavaScript.

Comment: So you need help on how to do it on the server or on how to do it with javascript ?

Comment: I know how to do it in JavaScript. I just want to be able to keep the template around even after rendering it on Server with Ruby on Rails. One way I could achieve that is through duplication. But I want a better solution.

Comment: I see ... then the only solution that I see is to duplicate it : once to process the template during page rendering and once in the page itself (or download it via an ajax request). I think that it is already what you wanted to do and I hardly see any other solution. Sorry I can't help you.